# Decimal input wrong java

Tags: java, input, decimal

The answer is incorrect in Decimal form however if the (input) answer is the full number it works. The decimal format works however if the user inputs the answer as a rounded decimal the system will print incorrect. It only works if the answer is not rounded please help :) I am still learning to code so anything is useful.

[image: Error from "right" input]

```
public class Generator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            /* Prints 10 random numbers
            Random num = new Random();

            int number;

            for(int counter=1; counter<=1;counter++){
                number = num.nextInt(10);
                System.out.println(number);
            }
            */

            Random num1 = new Random();
            Random num2 = new Random();
            Random num3 = new Random();;

            int number1;
            int number2;
            int number3;


            number1 = num1.nextInt(10) + 2;
            number2 = num2.nextInt(10) * 2;
            number3 = -num3.nextInt(10) * 2;

            System.out.println("Solve the quadratic: "+number1 + "x"+"\u00B2+" + number2 + "x" +  number3);

            double answer = -number2/2/number1+Math.pow(Math.pow(number2,2)-4*number1*number3,0.5)/2/number1;

            double answer2 = -number2/2/number1-Math.pow(Math.pow(number2,2)-4*number1*number3,0.5)/2/number1;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
            for (Number n : Arrays.asList(answer, answer2)) {
                Double d = n.doubleValue();
                System.out.println(df.format(d));
            }
            //System.out.println(answer); <---- works if answer is not rounded.
            System.out.println("Enter answer:");
            double x = scan.nextDouble();

            if(x == answer){
            System.out.println("Correct");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Try again");

            System.out.println("Enter answer:");
            double x1 = scan.nextDouble();
            if(x1 == answer){
                System.out.println("Correct");

            }else{
                System.out.println("Try again");
        }

    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You format the `answer` for printing it out, but this is the rounded value, therefore when you enter the rounded answer it will not equate to the `answer` value as it is the full, unrounded double value, so `x == answer` will always fail when rounding occurs.

Adding print statement of `answer` will show this to you, this is the output when you do so.

> Solve the quadratic: 5x²+6x-14
>       answer: 1.7776388834631178
>       rounded1: 1.7777
>       rounded2: -1.7776
>       Enter answer:
>       1.7777
>       Try again
>       Enter answer:
>       1.7776388834631178
>       Correct

You will need some way of comparing the input answer to the rounded answer, something like this would work

```
if(x == (double)Math.round(answer * 10000d) / 10000d)
```

Here the number of zeros indicate the number of decimals you want to use.